# Counting items from a table based on the number of appearances in another one

Tags: mysql, powerbi, dax

I have uploaded a MySQL database to PowerBI; this is how the data model looks like:

[image: PowerBI data model]

I'd like to reproduce this MySQL query with DAX:

```
SELECT
    concat(substring(ano, 1, 3), 0) AS decada,
    nombre_pais,
    nombre_ciudad,
    count(nombre_ciudad) AS numero
FROM
    paises
        NATURAL JOIN ciudades
            NATURAL JOIN autores
                NATURAL JOIN publican
                    NATURAL JOIN discos
                        NATURAL JOIN canciones
                            NATURAL JOIN listas_spotify
GROUP BY
    decada,
    nombre_ciudad
```

It calculates the number of times every city (from table `ciudades`) appears in the database depending on the number of songs (from table `canciones`) by bands (from table `autores`) located in that city, by decade (from table `listas_spotify`, that includes a date parameter).

Ordering by `numero`, I get a table like this:

```
decada, nombre_pais, nombre_ciudad, numero
1980, Inglaterra, Londres, 23
1990, Inglaterra, Londres, 15
1980, Inglaterra, Mánchester, 11
2000, EEUU, Austin, 11
2000, EEUU, Nueva York, 10
1980, EEUU, Boston, 9
1980, EEUU, Nueva York, 8
1990, Inglaterra, Mánchester, 7
1990, Inglaterra, Oxford, 7
...
```

If I directly upload this table to PowerBI, it's easy to create a graph like this (filtered just for five major cities):

[image: Cities appearances graph]

But I have no idea how to get it from the PowerBI data model using DAX. I don't expect a full solution to my issue, just to get to know how to relate tables in order to count the number of items from one depending on parameters from another, so I can recreate my SQL query with DAX syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd create a merge table using PowerQuery with all the fields you need and then do a Group By

Comment: I have reached that final table using `NATURALINNERJOIN()` -so now I have a lot of pointless intermediate tables within my model-, and then SUMMARIZE() it. I'll do some research about merging. Thanks!

Comment: Do it all in PowerQuery and check for Query Folding https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/power-query-folding This will make it pass the SQL back to the DB if you want to